# Does this sequence of functions converge in a distributional sense?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in W^{1,12/5}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (time-independent), let $K^{\epsilon}$ be a uniformly in $\epsilon$ bounded sequence in $L^{1}\cap L^{7/5}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and let
$$\tilde{K}^{\epsilon} := K^{\epsilon} \ast G^{\epsilon}$$
where $G^{\epsilon} := (\pi \epsilon)^{-3/2} \exp(-|x|^2/\epsilon)$. Does
$$f(x)(K^{\epsilon}-\tilde{K}^{\epsilon})$$
converge to zero in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^3)=(C^{\infty}_0)'(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^3)$, i.e. does

$$\iint f(x)(K^{\epsilon}-\tilde{K}^{\epsilon})\varphi dx dt \rightarrow 0$$

as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ where $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_0$?

The problem is that $f$ is in no $L^p$ with $p\leq 2$, otherwise one could use Plancherel, then Hölder and Hausdorff-Young.